# `King - Man + Woman = Queen` cannot be validated using spaCy word embedding calculations

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, word-embedding

Word embeddings are supposed to make calculations using words possible [as explained in this article](https://kawine.github.io/blog/nlp/2019/06/21/word-analogies.html). However, when using spaCy's pretained word embedding, this can not be reproduced, i.e. the difference between `King - Man + Woman` and `Queen` is not close to zero.

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
#spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

doc = nlp('queen king woman man')
queen, king, woman, man = doc[0].vector, doc[1].vector, doc[2].vector, doc[3].vector
vec = king - man + woman
vec - queen
```

The result is:

```
array([ 0.10928726,  1.5129069 ,  0.22144175, -1.0195163 , -0.88018465,
    1.0273552 , -0.42121184, -0.6132709 , -5.506116  , -1.8500991 ,
   -0.15576434, -1.1081355 ,  0.33168507, -3.3569758 , -3.671307  ,
    0.41009247,  5.0559406 ,  1.6673484 ,  1.6196246 ,  2.3392878 ,
   -1.4170032 ,  1.0845371 ,  1.1150997 ,  1.4959896 , -5.9387603 ,
    2.71976   , -5.1596265 , -2.1413157 , -2.0650306 , -0.90464056,
   -3.662921  , -1.9780679 ,  0.3792592 , -1.1127007 , -2.763383  ,
   -0.46687317, -3.3972526 , -1.0455723 ,  4.713142  , -1.3429235 ,
    1.4183658 , -1.38419   ,  3.2157912 ,  0.4593829 ,  2.57287   ,
   -5.232533  ,  2.007104  , -0.03439535, -2.5858183 ,  2.3942559 ,
   -2.2274508 ,  1.1235554 ,  1.8343859 , -3.809722  ,  2.3434563 ,
    6.6838984 , -0.79330105, -0.3786683 ,  0.5149512 , -2.567075  ,
   -4.5407395 ,  0.15355158,  0.4791546 ,  2.6068583 ,  0.06677404,
   -0.36967564, -5.109796  ,  0.45319676,  7.158951  ,  1.0552151 ,
   -0.72934663,  1.5460184 , -0.41246212, -3.068016  , -1.2780238 ,
   -2.256475  ,  0.20324552, -0.7423974 ,  2.6825244 , -1.8383589 ,
    2.2891805 ,  1.542151  , -2.3867102 ,  0.03401029, -0.70230985,
    1.4130044 , -2.416402  ,  0.6862675 , -2.270489  ,  3.9625044 ,
    2.463019  ,  1.3068041 ,  3.4472568 ,  5.8497505 ,  7.2417293 ,
   -1.8955674 ], dtype=float32)
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is due to the quality of the embedding loaded. When using larger embeddings, the result is getting much closer to zero.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp('queen king woman man')
queen, king, woman, man = doc[0].vector, doc[1].vector, doc[2].vector, doc[3].vector
vec = king - man + woman
vec - queen

array([ 0.10928726,  1.5129069 ,  0.22144175, -1.0195163 , -0.88018465,
        1.0273552 , -0.42121184, -0.6132709 , -5.506116  , -1.8500991 ,
       -0.15576434, -1.1081355 ,  0.33168507, -3.3569758 , -3.671307  ,
        0.41009247,  5.0559406 ,  1.6673484 ,  1.6196246 ,  2.3392878 ,
       -1.4170032 ,  1.0845371 ,  1.1150997 ,  1.4959896 , -5.9387603 ,
        2.71976   , -5.1596265 , -2.1413157 , -2.0650306 , -0.90464056,
       -3.662921  , -1.9780679 ,  0.3792592 , -1.1127007 , -2.763383  ,
       -0.46687317, -3.3972526 , -1.0455723 ,  4.713142  , -1.3429235 ,
        1.4183658 , -1.38419   ,  3.2157912 ,  0.4593829 ,  2.57287   ,
       -5.232533  ,  2.007104  , -0.03439535, -2.5858183 ,  2.3942559 ,
       -2.2274508 ,  1.1235554 ,  1.8343859 , -3.809722  ,  2.3434563 ,
        6.6838984 , -0.79330105, -0.3786683 ,  0.5149512 , -2.567075  ,
       -4.5407395 ,  0.15355158,  0.4791546 ,  2.6068583 ,  0.06677404,
       -0.36967564, -5.109796  ,  0.45319676,  7.158951  ,  1.0552151 ,
       -0.72934663,  1.5460184 , -0.41246212, -3.068016  , -1.2780238 ,
       -2.256475  ,  0.20324552, -0.7423974 ,  2.6825244 , -1.8383589 ,
        2.2891805 ,  1.542151  , -2.3867102 ,  0.03401029, -0.70230985,
        1.4130044 , -2.416402  ,  0.6862675 , -2.270489  ,  3.9625044 ,
        2.463019  ,  1.3068041 ,  3.4472568 ,  5.8497505 ,  7.2417293 ,
       -1.8955674 ], dtype=float32)
```

---

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
doc = nlp('queen king woman man')
queen, king, woman, man = doc[0].vector, doc[1].vector, doc[2].vector, doc[3].vector
vec = king - man + woman
vec - queen

array([ 0.10458702, -0.05152999, -0.01085299,  0.40603995,  0.111525  ,
        0.03181005, -0.18277001,  0.10793996,  0.22586   ,  0.42549992,
       -0.620518  ,  0.09305897, -0.0758817 , -0.29067168, -0.297841  ,
       -0.43369   , -0.44859397,  0.21168   , -0.172735  ,  0.24211   ,
        0.20211   , -0.15502006, -0.04844499, -0.202636  , -0.21129996,
        0.457768  ,  0.03138995,  0.13294101, -0.534806  , -0.07134694,
       -0.157518  , -0.05403006, -0.14246997, -0.773906  ,  0.15866998,
       -0.12601201, -0.19204   , -0.40347007,  0.05978   ,  0.5203604 ,
        0.37192   , -0.252379  , -0.097138  , -0.40504098,  0.25123   ,
       -0.03785798, -0.11933102, -0.00672996,  0.40258   ,  0.02721703,
       -0.29956898,  0.34834102, -0.15371901, -0.14056298,  0.17291501,
        0.73967993, -0.0257776 , -0.28438202, -0.337454  ,  0.12431702,
        0.063307  , -0.391515  , -0.24294749,  0.3378177 ,  0.37893206,
        0.14127994,  0.70388097,  0.021424  ,  0.142003  ,  0.20465   ,
       -0.36599994, -0.14310999, -0.17243698, -0.00424001,  0.67148   ,
       -0.17920549,  0.45753998,  0.17486003, -0.23000398,  0.06431001,
        0.13716793, -0.172827  , -0.32512403,  0.22375101, -0.3474555 ,
        0.447715  ,  0.28867   , -0.14638105, -0.04995   , -0.437648  ,
       -0.2236634 , -0.14245   ,  0.03281999, -0.16247103,  0.5124899 ,
       -0.40227997, -0.150479  , -0.38445002,  0.359772  ,  0.30387995,
        0.577236  ,  0.534451  ,  0.281598  ,  0.126359  , -0.019406  ,
       -0.26014996, -0.15996996, -0.15767002,  0.00154799,  0.195612  ,
       -0.13352397,  0.01087999, -0.080301  , -0.20445602, -0.11846301,
       -0.371925  ,  0.39347702,  0.26368502,  0.392657  ,  0.48374   ,
        0.06531   ,  0.068128  ,  0.11742002,  0.04229499,  0.10026699,
        0.30376   ,  0.06063001,  0.3936985 , -0.10366529,  0.065814  ,
        0.14065003,  0.17174399, -0.20236002, -0.55088   , -0.722872  ,
       -0.48885   , -0.37717   ,  0.07013199, -0.52826   ,  0.096489  ,
        0.5985999 , -0.13812901, -0.11418399, -0.190035  ,  0.06799701,
        0.02872499,  0.387542  ,  0.00787   , -0.623389  , -0.09111011,
       -0.22364   , -0.1886197 , -0.20119   ,  0.22608899, -0.24934301,
        0.08535001, -0.27039596,  0.30038005, -0.090203  , -0.14802799,
        0.14603001,  0.21248001,  0.118833  , -0.07153228, -0.12797996,
       -0.274443  ,  0.30433598,  0.29837996, -0.01640302,  0.11600998,
       -0.33268997, -0.056754  ,  0.13773698, -0.188018  , -0.51105094,
       -0.2561026 , -0.07734999, -0.457643  ,  0.12696004, -0.25476858,
        0.01485402, -0.27168003, -0.09315271, -0.18197   ,  0.46563497,
        0.34945   ,  0.27662   , -0.138596  ,  0.200928  , -0.34992003,
       -0.48564997, -0.603999  , -0.181443  , -0.11616989,  0.129803  ,
        0.02417099,  0.05545059,  0.117446  , -0.03544599, -0.57339   ,
        0.44310898,  0.33150995,  0.01238599, -0.21157703, -0.03491596,
        0.26410997, -0.22768001, -0.252998  , -0.23517999,  0.48754   ,
        0.194835  , -0.27317   , -0.440702  ,  0.367029  ,  0.09925799,
       -0.06908001, -0.14320281,  0.22666103,  0.2794511 ,  0.29843   ,
        0.21248499, -0.635843  ,  0.20785001,  0.483295  , -0.47914696,
       -0.03455502,  0.34644902, -0.37480602, -0.15627   ,  0.12277907,
       -0.04933499,  0.005468  ,  0.00519997, -0.37172398, -0.175451  ,
       -0.18385059, -0.21175501, -0.313944  ,  0.07360198, -0.01590204,
       -0.17416   , -0.00090003,  0.11262399, -0.48282   , -0.10517   ,
        0.05565304,  0.32160503, -0.24056101, -0.30389994, -0.5073231 ,
        0.33911803, -0.23648998,  0.06108901,  0.23029798, -0.02688998,
        0.08346   ,  0.17561206,  0.331848  , -0.09330803,  0.2918205 ,
        0.277062  , -0.32242298, -0.002744  ,  0.36982   ,  0.51171   ,
       -0.39322   , -0.16557002, -0.18774   , -0.01507998, -0.284651  ,
       -0.07072806, -0.05853601, -0.06321001, -0.09849399, -0.09514015,
       -0.23703995, -0.17931   ,  0.38357297,  0.01018202,  0.10888296,
        0.29964393,  0.12595999,  0.605805  ,  0.04320699,  0.18856   ,
        0.636185  , -0.18775499,  0.421264  , -0.15406296, -0.36692598,
        0.094318  ,  0.02511001,  0.06609299, -0.17440999,  0.00357999,
        0.08757752,  0.04765201,  0.27466798,  0.7439101 , -0.01412702],
      dtype=float32)
```

---

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
doc = nlp('queen king woman man')
queen, king, woman, man = doc[0].vector, doc[1].vector, doc[2].vector, doc[3].vector
vec = king - man + woman
vec - queen

array([ 0.10458702, -0.05152999, -0.01085299,  0.40603995,  0.111525  ,
        0.03181005, -0.18277001,  0.10793996,  0.22586   ,  0.42549992,
       -0.620518  ,  0.09305897, -0.0758817 , -0.29067168, -0.297841  ,
       -0.43369   , -0.44859397,  0.21168   , -0.172735  ,  0.24211   ,
        0.20211   , -0.15502006, -0.04844499, -0.202636  , -0.21129996,
        0.457768  ,  0.03138995,  0.13294101, -0.534806  , -0.07134694,
       -0.157518  , -0.05403006, -0.14246997, -0.773906  ,  0.15866998,
       -0.12601201, -0.19204   , -0.40347007,  0.05978   ,  0.5203604 ,
        0.37192   , -0.252379  , -0.097138  , -0.40504098,  0.25123   ,
       -0.03785798, -0.11933102, -0.00672996,  0.40258   ,  0.02721703,
       -0.29956898,  0.34834102, -0.15371901, -0.14056298,  0.17291501,
        0.73967993, -0.0257776 , -0.28438202, -0.337454  ,  0.12431702,
        0.063307  , -0.391515  , -0.24294749,  0.3378177 ,  0.37893206,
        0.14127994,  0.70388097,  0.021424  ,  0.142003  ,  0.20465   ,
       -0.36599994, -0.14310999, -0.17243698, -0.00424001,  0.67148   ,
       -0.17920549,  0.45753998,  0.17486003, -0.23000398,  0.06431001,
        0.13716793, -0.172827  , -0.32512403,  0.22375101, -0.3474555 ,
        0.447715  ,  0.28867   , -0.14638105, -0.04995   , -0.437648  ,
       -0.2236634 , -0.14245   ,  0.03281999, -0.16247103,  0.5124899 ,
       -0.40227997, -0.150479  , -0.38445002,  0.359772  ,  0.30387995,
        0.577236  ,  0.534451  ,  0.281598  ,  0.126359  , -0.019406  ,
       -0.26014996, -0.15996996, -0.15767002,  0.00154799,  0.195612  ,
       -0.13352397,  0.01087999, -0.080301  , -0.20445602, -0.11846301,
       -0.371925  ,  0.39347702,  0.26368502,  0.392657  ,  0.48374   ,
        0.06531   ,  0.068128  ,  0.11742002,  0.04229499,  0.10026699,
        0.30376   ,  0.06063001,  0.3936985 , -0.10366529,  0.065814  ,
        0.14065003,  0.17174399, -0.20236002, -0.55088   , -0.722872  ,
       -0.48885   , -0.37717   ,  0.07013199, -0.52826   ,  0.096489  ,
        0.5985999 , -0.13812901, -0.11418399, -0.190035  ,  0.06799701,
        0.02872499,  0.387542  ,  0.00787   , -0.623389  , -0.09111011,
       -0.22364   , -0.1886197 , -0.20119   ,  0.22608899, -0.24934301,
        0.08535001, -0.27039596,  0.30038005, -0.090203  , -0.14802799,
        0.14603001,  0.21248001,  0.118833  , -0.07153228, -0.12797996,
       -0.274443  ,  0.30433598,  0.29837996, -0.01640302,  0.11600998,
       -0.33268997, -0.056754  ,  0.13773698, -0.188018  , -0.51105094,
       -0.2561026 , -0.07734999, -0.457643  ,  0.12696004, -0.25476858,
        0.01485402, -0.27168003, -0.09315271, -0.18197   ,  0.46563497,
        0.34945   ,  0.27662   , -0.138596  ,  0.200928  , -0.34992003,
       -0.48564997, -0.603999  , -0.181443  , -0.11616989,  0.129803  ,
        0.02417099,  0.05545059,  0.117446  , -0.03544599, -0.57339   ,
        0.44310898,  0.33150995,  0.01238599, -0.21157703, -0.03491596,
        0.26410997, -0.22768001, -0.252998  , -0.23517999,  0.48754   ,
        0.194835  , -0.27317   , -0.440702  ,  0.367029  ,  0.09925799,
       -0.06908001, -0.14320281,  0.22666103,  0.2794511 ,  0.29843   ,
        0.21248499, -0.635843  ,  0.20785001,  0.483295  , -0.47914696,
       -0.03455502,  0.34644902, -0.37480602, -0.15627   ,  0.12277907,
       -0.04933499,  0.005468  ,  0.00519997, -0.37172398, -0.175451  ,
       -0.18385059, -0.21175501, -0.313944  ,  0.07360198, -0.01590204,
       -0.17416   , -0.00090003,  0.11262399, -0.48282   , -0.10517   ,
        0.05565304,  0.32160503, -0.24056101, -0.30389994, -0.5073231 ,
        0.33911803, -0.23648998,  0.06108901,  0.23029798, -0.02688998,
        0.08346   ,  0.17561206,  0.331848  , -0.09330803,  0.2918205 ,
        0.277062  , -0.32242298, -0.002744  ,  0.36982   ,  0.51171   ,
       -0.39322   , -0.16557002, -0.18774   , -0.01507998, -0.284651  ,
       -0.07072806, -0.05853601, -0.06321001, -0.09849399, -0.09514015,
       -0.23703995, -0.17931   ,  0.38357297,  0.01018202,  0.10888296,
        0.29964393,  0.12595999,  0.605805  ,  0.04320699,  0.18856   ,
        0.636185  , -0.18775499,  0.421264  , -0.15406296, -0.36692598,
        0.094318  ,  0.02511001,  0.06609299, -0.17440999,  0.00357999,
        0.08757752,  0.04765201,  0.27466798,  0.7439101 , -0.01412702],
      dtype=float32)
```